# Change query string/ url or replace a portion of url/wordpress permalink

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, url

I am working on a wordpress site.

A page contains a listing of different insurance companies and each list item has a button which redirects to a wordpress page where I display other details of that insurance company.
I pass the ID of the company with the url and display the records through ID.

```
<a href="<?php echo $row->Kiesuwverzekering."?id=".$row->health_id;?>">
<img src="<?php echo $img_path."img-1.png"; ?>" />
</a>
```

`$row->Kiesuwverzekering`  is the link of that page, i want to display more details of company.

When redirected to that page url becomes

```
http://xyz.net/zorgverzekeringg/?id=40
```

Now I want it to be like -

```
http://xyz.net/zorgverzekeringg/companyname
```

Can I replace ?id=40 with companyname? Or should I pass company name in url? If yes then what if company name is like "my company"(without ") I mean what if company name have longer name having space?

Comment: permalink setting can help you http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: It all depends on how the page you are navigating to is configured. If it requires the ID from the query string, then you would also need to change edit that page. Also, what are your 'insurance companies?' Are they Posts, Terms, Pages, or what? Without knowing that it is difficult to say how to create the structure you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can put page name/identifier instead of passing page id. Wordpress create a permanent link for each page. so first look page URL then get that part and add it in your base URL.

Comment: id in not the id of page. id is table id in database

Comment: you are useing like mydomain.com?page_id=232?